# Visual Studio 2013 Team Explorer : Submit changes to an open Code Review

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, alm, team-explorer

I submitted some code for review.  I got feedback from the reviewer.
I made the changes to the code.

How can I submit the new changes back to the existing review for reappraisal.

I do not see a button anywhere.  All I can do is Complete or abandon.
Do I have to setup a new Code Review?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the way we do it. Technically speaking, your changes have failed the code review so your code review is now complete. You should have some feedback which you can use to make some changes to your code and try again.

When you request a review, your changes are bundled in a shelveset and in order to see the differences since the last lot of differences, I imagine would be a difficult task for the code reviewer to handle.

Usually, we request a review from a number of people initially but then we will send the re-review only to the person(s) that rejected it.